# Ruby sort code without arrays explanation of example

Tags: ruby, sorting

I'm new to ruby. I'm working on an assignment and the given example is not explained.  Can someone explain how this sort code works?  It takes 3 inputs and sorts them alphabetically but I cannot understand how it does this.

```
# sort
n1, n2 = n2, n1 if n1 > n2
n1, n3 = n3, n1 if n1 > n3
n2, n3 = n3, n2 if n2 > n3
```

Comment: It's not sorting alphabetically, it's sorting by value, from least to greatest. If you pass in characters it'll sort alphabetically, pass in numerics and it sorts by their values; See my examples below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`n1, n2 = n2, n1` is using  parallel assignment to swap values stored in `n1` and `n2`. It’s only done `if n1>n2`. That way, after the first line, the `n1` value will be less than the `n2` value.

The same happens on the second row which is swapping values of `n1` and `n3` to make sure the value in `n1` is the smallest.

In the third row `n1` is the smallest value now. You have to sort `n2` and `n3`, so you’re doing the swap again to keep `n2` smaller than `n3`.

Your sorting method should return `[n1,n2,n3]`.

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote the `if` from trailing to block forms for readability as trailing `if` conditions reverse how we read the line and can make it harder to understand when first encountering them. Add in the parallel assignment and it can be confusing at first.

Meditate on these:

```
n1 = 1
n2 = 2
n3 = 3

[n1, n2, n3] # => [1, 2, 3]
if n1 > n2 # => false
  n1, n2 = n2, n1 # => 
end

if n1 > n3 # => false
  n1, n3 = n3, n1 # => 
end

if n2 > n3 # => false
  n2, n3 = n3, n2 # => 
end
[n1, n2, n3] # => [1, 2, 3]
```

```
n1, n2, n3 = 2, 1, 3
[n1, n2, n3] # => [2, 1, 3]
if n1 > n2 # => true
  n1, n2 = n2, n1 # => [1, 2]
end

if n1 > n3 # => false
  n1, n3 = n3, n1 # => 
end

if n2 > n3 # => false
  n2, n3 = n3, n2 # => 
end
[n1, n2, n3] # => [1, 2, 3]
```

```
n1, n2, n3 = 3, 1, 2
n1, n2 = n2, n1 if n1 > n2 # => [1, 3]
n1, n3 = n3, n1 if n1 > n3 # => nil
n2, n3 = n3, n2 if n2 > n3 # => [2, 3]
[n1, n2, n3] # => [1, 2, 3]

n1, n2, n3 = 3, 2, 1
n1, n2 = n2, n1 if n1 > n2 # => [2, 3]
n1, n3 = n3, n1 if n1 > n3 # => [1, 2]
n2, n3 = n3, n2 if n2 > n3 # => [2, 3]
[n1, n2, n3] # => [1, 2, 3]
```

```
n1, n2, n3 = %w[c b a]
n1, n2 = n2, n1 if n1 > n2 # => ["b", "c"]
n1, n3 = n3, n1 if n1 > n3 # => ["a", "b"]
n2, n3 = n3, n2 if n2 > n3 # => ["b", "c"]
[n1, n2, n3] # => ["a", "b", "c"]

n1, n2, n3 = %w[b A 1]
n1, n2 = n2, n1 if n1 > n2 # => ["A", "b"]
n1, n3 = n3, n1 if n1 > n3 # => ["1", "A"]
n2, n3 = n3, n2 if n2 > n3 # => ["A", "b"]
[n1, n2, n3] # => ["1", "A", "b"]

n1, n2, n3 = %w[b 02 1]
n1, n2 = n2, n1 if n1 > n2 # => ["02", "b"]
n1, n3 = n3, n1 if n1 > n3 # => nil
n2, n3 = n3, n2 if n2 > n3 # => ["1", "b"]
[n1, n2, n3] # => ["02", "1", "b"]

n1, n2, n3 = %w[3 2 1]
n1, n2 = n2, n1 if n1 > n2 # => ["2", "3"]
n1, n3 = n3, n1 if n1 > n3 # => ["1", "2"]
n2, n3 = n3, n2 if n2 > n3 # => ["2", "3"]
[n1, n2, n3] # => ["1", "2", "3"]
```

Comparing values can be confusing until you understand their sorting order is based on the type of the value. Characters usually sort in ASCII's order... unless you're using EBCDIC from IBM mainframes, but hopefully you're not.

Ruby has tools that make it easier to visualize what's happening. I happen to be currently using "[Seeing Is Believing](https://github.com/JoshCheek/seeing_is_believing)".